# Get invoking user ID (only) from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL, so this may be a dumb question, but I haven't found an answer specificly after googling and digging here on SO.

All I'm attempting to do is get the user ID, and only the user ID, of the invoking user of an insert or update on a given table.  I'm not asking for any help with a trigger in this question, so don't worry about that.

```
SELECT user()
```

Gives: `user@[IP Address]`

```
SELECT current_user()
```

Gives: `user@%`

**Minor problem:** I only want `user`

**My Question:**

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Is there a cleaner, or more readable way to get just `user` rather than having to use something like`substr(user(),1,instr(user(),'@')-1)` ? I've written some triggers in Oracle where I could just use the `USER` value for what I need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A mysql user is actually what you're getting - it's always a composite of user@host. `user@example.com` is a completely different account from `user@%`, even though the `user` portion is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manual page [says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_user):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1);
```

Comment: It's amazing how much I can search, yet miss something like that. That's pretty much what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The docs specifically say to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_user

Quote:

> You can extract only the user name part like this:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1);
>         -> 'davida'
> ```